# Where's definitive reference on string formatting

Tags: java

does anyone know of a good online resource that simply and definitevly explains how to use the string formatter method...?

I need to write a series of "records" into a set ascii text files. I need to "delimit" each "record" with a cr-lf sequence in a windows 2008 server environment. 
Therefore I'm trying to figure out how to add a \r\n character string at the end of each "record". I tried a "record_string.append(CR) and LF" ; but it didn't work.

Thanks much

Guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specifically need to add CR LF to the end of each record (carriage return, linefeed), then you can just use exactly `\r\n`. The `\r` translates to a carriage return, and `\n` to linefeed. For example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("some data");
// ...
sb.append("\r\n");  // add CR LF record separator
```

You can find the exact list of escape sequences that exist in Java in [section 3.10.6](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.6) of the Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on the [`Formatter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class appears to be comprehensive.

It has this to say about line separators:

> **Line Separator**
>
> The conversion does not correspond to any argument.
>
> 'n' -   the platform-specific line separator as returned by `System.getProperty("line.separator").`
> Flags, width, and precision are not applicable. If any are provided an IllegalFormatFlagsException, IllegalFormatWidthException, and IllegalFormatPrecisionException, respectively will be thrown.

Comment: Note that `System.getProperty("line.separator")` returns the default line separator character(s) for the system that the program is running on. On Mac OS X or Linux it will most likely return a string with just a linefeed; on Windows it will return a string with CR LF. If you specifically need to always insert CR LF, then don't use this; just insert CR LF into the string yourself.

Answer (score -2):

Just do the:
record_string = record_string + "\n"

on widnows \n means CR-LF

Or you can use FileWriter to use writeLine(record);

Comment: 'on windows \n means CR-LF'. No it doesn't. It means a line feed, everywhere.